# Huawei Automatic Speech Recognition Limitation - Service Unavailable Error on PICKUP UI

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-ml-kit

I'm working on the Translator application for Huawei App Gallery and I come to know through [Huawei-Doc](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/ml-asr-0000001050066212) that Automatic Speech Recognition is currently supporting 11 language

> Automatic speech recognition (ASR) can recognize speech not longer than 60s and convert the input speech into text in real time. This service uses industry-leading deep learning technologies to achieve a recognition accuracy of over 95%. Currently, Mandarin Chinese (including Chinese-English bilingual speech), English, French, German, Spanish, Italian, Arabic, Russian, Thai, Malay, and Filipino can be recognized.

But on the other hand, [Real-Time Translation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/hiai-Guides/real-time-translation-0000001050040079) is supporting 40 languages. I'm using ASR for conversion but 29 languages code in Real- Time Translation shows Service Unavailable on PICKUP UI. What should be other alternative I can use to achieve the conversion for other language. Do Huawei give support to other languages in near Future?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your feedback.

> `Service Unavailable Error`

Please check the network environment. Currently, there is no solution for conversion. And according to the R&D team, other languages will be added in the near future. For details, Please stay tuned on the official websites.